# Changing rotation_mode from `YXZ` to `XYZ` without changing orientation?

Tags: coordinates, conversion

I am writing an importer in Blender that appends a object and then moves and rotates that object by some stored values I have created in Unity and saved to a Json file.

I found that in order to achieve the desired rotation I must first set my object to `rotation_mode='YXZ'` then I can create a new Vector with the order (X,Z,-Y) and my object will be rotated correctly:

```
degToRad = math.pi / 180

myobj.rotation_mode = 'YXZ'
jRot = json['rotation']
myobj.rotation_euler = Vector((jRot['x']*degToRad, jRot['z']*degToRad, -jRot['y']*degToRad ))

#Do something here to convert rotation back to XYZ...

myobj.rotation_mode = 'XYZ' #this causes the object to rotate unexpectedly
```

But when I attempt to revert the `rotation_mode` back to XYZ the object then rotates to some other orientation and I don't know how to prevent.

I am not sure if I am correctly changing handedness and up/forward with my above example but it seems to work ok.

I am curious if it is possible to change the rotation_mode from `YXZ` to `XYZ` without the orientation of my object changing?

Or is it possible to somehow apply a "converted" rotation so I can just keep the rotation_mode as `XYZ`?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use matrices, or quaternions. Unlike euler rotations, matrices or quaternions are comprised values which are order-independent.

There is no need to apply the "wrong" `YXZ` rotation to the object. You can store it in an `mathutils.Euler` object, the convert it to a `mathutils.Matrix` object and finally convert it back using a different rotation order.

```
import bpy
import mathutils

ob = bpy.context.active_object

x, y, z = 1, 2, 3

rot_YXZ = mathutils.Euler((x, y, z), 'YXZ')
rot_mat = rot_YXZ.to_matrix()
rot_XYZ = rot_mat.to_euler('XYZ')

ob.rotation_mode = 'XYZ'
ob.rotation_euler = rot_XYZ
```

The `mathutils.Matrix.to_euler` method takes the desired rotation order as the first argument.

Comment: That was a wonderful explanation and a perfect solution. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it helped, the [`mathutils`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.html#module-mathutils) module provides many useful conversion methods. For a deeper understanding I recommend [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d4EgbgTm0Bg) as an introduction to the math of quaternion rotations, if you are interested in the logic behind these functions.